# iPad app to gesture control PC

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

I am looking for an iPad app that allows me to map gestures to keyboard buttons and then pass these along to my PC. The idea being that I want to control Windows Media Center with gestures. So a swipe up would be the up arrow, something else the enter key, etc.

I am not interested in a full RDP client, I just want to send keypresses to my PC.

My google-fu and appstore-fu are failing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether they will do exactly what you want, but [HippoRemote](http://hipporemote.com/) or [Mobile Mouse](http://mobilemouse.com/) should be worth a look, and both have (at least some) support for multi-touch trackpad and gestures. Both have Windows servers and should work on the iPad too.

HippoRemote actually has a dedicated profile for controlling Windows Media Centre, so unless you specifically want to use gestures, this might be the way to go.

[image]

Comment: Hippo does not have a native iPad app which is disappointing. The app has been around for over two years so I guess I'm not holding out any hope that they will. Mobile Mouse has a native app that I have chosen to use. They allow gesture mapping, but only to some esoteric combinations. I really wish I could rebind basic ones. Like single tap or single swipe. Instead you can only bind triple finger tap or triple finger swipe. This is the best answer I have found though.

Comment: @mrtsherman: Yeah, I noticed the lack of a native HippoRemote iPad app when I posted the answer. I included it though as their blog mentions a few articles about using it on an iPad. As you say, you'd have thought they would have made an iPad version by now, but maybe its worth an email to their support to see what they say?